# JavaScript Looping through array and replace all numbers untill array = 0 from a random input number

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have one array, then I have a random number input that changes the value to 0 if is into the array. I have to loop this random number until I change all the array numbers to 0. I cannot loop it. I can only replace one

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;

 for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  if (array1 !== 0) {
    if (n == array1[i]) {
        array1[i] = 0;
    }
    continue
   }
  break
 }
console.log(n);
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: `array1` will never be `0`, since it's an array, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

You could try leveraging [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) within a  [`while statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

See below for a rough example.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const goal = [...array].fill(0)

while (JSON.stringify(array) != JSON.stringify(goal)) {

  const n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1
  console.log(`n: ${n}`)
  
  const index = array.indexOf(n)
  if (index >= 0) array[index] = 0
  
}

console.log(`Complete: ${array}`)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gives the same result as my code. It should loop, so once it catches one number it checks another number and set it as 0 until all the numbers on the array become 0.Result should be 
[0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: No problem. See above.